# 5.1.1.1 Program structure in C99

Tags: c99

> A C program need not all be translated at the same time. The text of the program is kept
> in units called source files, (or preprocessing files) in this International Standard. A
> source file together with all the headers and source files included via the preprocessing
> directive #include is known as a preprocessing translation unit. After preprocessing, a
> preprocessing translation unit is called a translation unit. **Previously translated translation
> units may be preserved individually or in libraries.** The separate translation units of a
> program communicate by (for example) calls to functions whose identifiers have external
> linkage, manipulation of objects whose identifiers have external linkage, or manipulation
> of data files. Translation units may be separately translated and then later linked to
> produce an executable program.

I'm suffering from **bold sentence**. I think the sentence doesn't seem appropriate when considering entire clause's flow(this thought must be faulse as it is ANSI's documentation). It may be caused by my poor English or lack of Computer Science knowledge. I googled several times and searched all of the words and idioms, but still don't know.

Q1. **Previously `translated` translation units may be preserved individually or in libraries.** Does this sentence have the same meaning as 
**previously `preprocessed` translation units may be preserved individually or in libraries**?
That is, is the word `translation units` between the sentence and previous one exactly the same?
Q2. What does `individually` mean? `~ may be preserved individually.` Where is it preserved??
You can give me another explanation to say what the sentence refer to instead of answering my questions if my question is not clear or hard to understand. Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is due to poor English skills as you are pointing out. I'll try to give my interpretation, not being a native English speaker myself.

You write code. The quoted directive states that code is stored in atomic entities called "source files" or "preprocessing files".

You then compile this code into an executable or other binary form. The "preprocessing file" that you wrote in a human-readable format is now converted into a binary file that a human cannot read.

Let us say your project is quite large and has more than one source code file. You might have completed a portion of the project, for example the one in charge of Serial Port Connection. You compile that and now you have binary files. You may **preserve** those binaries and use them as **libraries** and import them into the remainder of your project, by linking them.

The linkage is done in source code, by importing existing stuff, and when compiling, creating the machine-level links. You do not re-compile the Serial port Connection, because you took the previously compiled library and **preserved** it (for later use).

The binary file is a file, maybe something like `library.o` or `library.dll` etc.

Comment: You give me nice sight and relevant thing of my question! The key point is the verb **preserve** mean storing compiled thing. By the way, can you say a detail about compiler's link? Compiler meet header file followed by preprocessing directive nested by <, > first. But there is only function prototype in it, not a function definition. Then does stdio.h has command line to make compiler link to library file? This additional question is nothing to do with my original question but I think you can give answer me. Your answer is so informative!

Comment: As you say, it has nothing to do with the original question. I encourage you to open a separate question for that. In general, yes: the linkage is provided like that for files that are source (e.g. stdio.h), but is imported in a different way if they are binaries (e.g. stdio.dll). This is too long to go in detail in a comment, because of search paths, compiler architecture and so on...